# Circuit to switch negative to negative, or positive to positive connection

Tags: transistors, mosfet, relay, switching

I am wondering if there is a negative to negative (and/or positive to positive) switch.  I know mechanical relays work, but I need an *electronic* way of doing it.  Is there a transistor that functions as such? or any other semiconductors?

**Edit**

I have 2 batteries, 12V  (both the same), similar to the link below.  They are connected in parallel.  I need to switch the positive and negative connections of the batteries, to break the connection. I would like to have these switched controlled by a micro-controller and for it to be electronic.

Any help is appreciated and thanks!

[image: parallel batteries circuit]

[https://www.amazon.com/Power-Sonic-PS-1290-Rechargeable-Battery-Terminals/dp/B002L6R130/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002L6R130)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to switch both the negative line and the positive line with the same switch?

Comment: Hi, no these would be 2 separate switches.  Basically its a parallel circuit that I am trying to have controlled by a switch.  I had it working with relays, but I need it electronically controlled.  I tried mosfets, but because of the polarity, it does not work.

Comment: Still not enough information. What voltage and current? Can you post your schematic? Why do you need to switch both positive and negative? Switching either will kill the load. Hit the edit link below your question and try to fix it up. (Read it back from the point of view of someone who has no idea if you're trying to switch an LED or a 100 kW electric catapult before you click 'Submit'.)

Comment: You must not do this without knowing the battery voltages and ESR's where I = ΔV/ESR(1+2)  ,  otherwise poof. You do not need 2 swtiches,

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if there is a negative to negative (and/or positive to positive) switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGFOp1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A double-pole, single-throw (DPST) switch can be used to connect negative to negative and positive to positive.*

> I know mechanical relays work, but I need an electrical way of doing it. Is there a transistor that functions as such? or any other semiconductors?

Perhaps you mean that you are looking for an *electronic* solution rather than an electro-mechanical solution. The answer is yes but we don't have enough information in your question.

Comment: I have amended the question.  Thanks and appreciated!